# Cannot log in to odoo server

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I study about odoo specificly in create data in odoo now. I try for transfer backup database file from other device to my localhost but got error when i try login. In web it says

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

When i try look in odoo file log inside odoo folder, i got this error

```
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'res.users' object has no attribute 'sidebar_type'
Template: 178
Path: /templates/t/t/t[4]
Node: <t t-set="body_classname" t-value="'o_web_client mk_sidebar_type_' + 
request.env.user.sidebar_type or 'large'"/> - - -
```

I also still learn python so i dont really understand how to solve this problem. Can anyone provide me how to solve this?

Comment: If you copy a database from somewhere else and restore it locally, make sure you also have the same structure for your modules/apps locally. It seems like it's complaining about something the original system has, but yours does not.

Comment: It is useful to look at the log when you start the server up. First errors/warnings can give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a database xml-view using the field 'sidebar_type',
which has been created in a python file of a (custom) module on your "origin odoo device",
but this module is not installed on your target device (localhost).

Solution :

1. looking for 'sidebar_type' in the python files of the installed applications and modules on your "origin odoo device" (custom modules are likely located in src/odoo/user directory).
2. installing the corresponding module (containing this file) on your target device... and restart odoo server